# PHP data/file caching to handle out-of-memory scripts when webcrawling --- What's a good approach?

Tags: php, caching, out-of-memory

I hope someone can help me out with this problem I've been facing.  I've written a spider that uses the cURL and DOMDocument libraries to pull back pages from a website, traversing the site links to find and pull back data from even more pages.  The data I pull out specifically are keywords (all the words on the page that aren't html/script code), which later get stored to a mySQL database (along with crawl/page information, such as the URL, parent URL, runtime, keyword counts, etc.).

My problem is in regards to memory, more specifically, running out of it.  If the spider only goes down 1 level from the top of the site, that could be 500 links, and in my tests so far it averages to about a million keywords encountered.  Memory starts to get eaten up fairly quickly, and if I try to run subsequent spiders for other websites in the same script, I often run into out-of-memory errors.  To address the latter issue I plan on implementing pcntl to run some of the additional spiders in parallel, but it still doesn't address the possibility of individual spiders running out of memory just from the sheer volume of data they might extract.

My question is, are there typical approaches for how to handle these sorts of out-of-memory issues for applications that process variably large amounts of data?  At first I implemented APC caching to try and store the keyword data as I was going along, but then I discovered that APC is used strictly for opcode caching, which seems to mean it only stores opcode into RAM to speed webserver access for frequently accessed PHP code (which for my purposes was redundant, and in any case, my spider application is supposed to run as a cron job anyways).  Should I try caching the keyword data to a file/files as the spider moves along, or are there any libraries/frameworks I should be considering that would help me move in the right direction?  I just don't want to make the same mistake twice of trying an approach thinking it's going to work, and then finding out I was spinning my wheels in the end.  Thanks so much for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: Sounds like you're creating a denial of service engine by mistake. You're not using your database for anything, just reading a slew of pages and sites and keeping all the information in memory, hoping to write it to the database when it finishes reading the whole internet?

Comment: Oh no, it doesn't read the whole internet, only the first few levels of linked pages off the top of any given website (I guess I should have been more specific on that point).  I'm trying to generate statistics for keyword trends is the idea, but I need a way to prevent the memory from running out as I'm pulling back data.